# WPF how to retrieve binded property in code behind

Tags: wpf, binding, datagrid

In my legacy project I need to get the binding property name via code behind. The XAML:

```
<DataGridTextColumn MinWidth="180" MaxWidth="180" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding ConfigObject.MAC_Descr}" Header="Descr" Foreground="Black">
    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="6,12" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsDirty}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="TextBlock.Background" Value="{StaticResource IsDirtyColor}" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
    <DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5,12"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

The event I use:

```
private void Row_DoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightCtrl))
    {
        DataGridCell row = sender as DataGridCell;
        if (row == null) return;

        // Binding column name??
        string bindingExpression = row.GetBindingExpression(TextBlock.TextProperty).ResolvedSourcePropertyName;
    }
}
```

Basically in the case above I need to retrieve the "MAC_Descr". Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
private void OnCellDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightCtrl))
    {
        if (!(sender is DataGridCell cell)) return;
        if (!(cell.Column is DataGridTextColumn column)) return;
        if (!(column.Binding is Binding binding)) return;

        var path = binding.Path.Path;
    }            
}
```

Comment: Well I've already retrieved the dataContext but since I have several columns with different binding property, I need to basically get the name of property, in the case above, MAC_Desc

Comment: Okay, so you just need the *name* of the property. I didn't get that specifically from your question.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Cast the `Content` of the cell to a `TextBox` or `TextBlock` depending on whether the cell is editable:

```
DataGridCell row = sender as DataGridCell;
if (row == null) return;

TextBox textBox = row.Content as TextBox;
if (textBox == null) return;

string bindingExpression = textBox.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty)
    .ResolvedSourcePropertyName;
```